# Issue with reflection in msbuild, devenv is good

Tags: msbuild, system.reflection

I have gone through SO questions related to this and could not find any for this issue and hence, I am asking this question.

I have a buildtask (added as `AfterBuild` target), to validate types names.  These type names are fully qualified type names from the silverlight projects that are being build.

To resolve these type names, I use `Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType()`.  To load the dependent assemblies I handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` event to load project specific assemblies from the project output path and silverlight base assemblies from the silverlight installation path using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(filepath)`.

**This works perfectly fine, when I build the projects in VS2010**, but **fails when I build with MSBuild** i.e. `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe "C:\Root\branches\x.x.x\clients.sln" /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug "/p:Platform=Any CPU" /v:quiet /maxcpucount:1`

While building with MSBuild, the `ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` event is fired for `"System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"` and this was loaded from the silverlight installation path.  But, the probing is trying for this system assembly in `"C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/System.DLL"`, which fail as the major version wont match.

Following is the stripped version of my code, specific to this problem:

```
  public class ValidateTypeTask : Task
  {
       public override bool Execute()
       {
            Initialize();

            List<string> typeNames = GetTypes();
            foreach (var typeName in typeNames)
            {
                var isResolved = IsResolvable(typeName);
                if (!isResolved)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            CleanUp();

            return true;
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve);
        }

        Assembly CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Assembly loadedAssembly = null;
            Exception loadedException = null;
            try
            {
                loadedAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);//this will fail always
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                loadedException = ex;
            }

            if (loadedAssembly != null)
            {
                return loadedAssembly;
            }

            string assemblyPath = string.Empty;
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
            if (args.Name.StartsWith("System"))
            {
                assemblyPath = @"c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0";
            }
            else
            {
                assemblyPath = @"C:\Root\branches\x.x.x\bin\debug";
            }
            assemblyPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.dll", assemblyPath, assemblyName.Name);
            if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
            {
                loadedAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
            }

            if (loadedAssembly == null)
            {
                throw loadedException;
            }

            return loadedAssembly;
        }
        private void CleanUp()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve -= new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve);
        }
        private List<string> GetTypes()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
        private bool IsResolvable(string typeName)
        {
            Type resolvedType = null;
            try
            {
                resolvedType = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(typeName, true, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            if (resolvedType != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

The exception I get is as follows:

```
  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  File name: 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
  at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ignoreCase)
  at  in c:\root\x.xx.x\BuildTasks\ValidateTypesTask.cs line xxx

  Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
  Running under executable  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
  --- A detailed error log follows. 

  === Pre-bind state information ===
  LOG: User = domain\username
  LOG: DisplayName = System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
  (Fully-specified)
  LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/
  LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
  Calling assembly : (Unknown).
  ===
  LOG: This is an inspection only bind.
  LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe.Config
  LOG: Using host configuration file: 
  LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
  LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/System.DLL.
  WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
  ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I have also tried including the silverlight assemblies path into AssemblySearchPaths project property to let this be part of the probing urls and still the same.

Comment: Try to either update the project references or pass ToolsVersion=2.0

Comment: @KMoraz I have tried removing and adding System assembly reference, just to update the project references and that did not help.  I cannot set ToolsVersion to 2 as the target is Silverlight 4.0.  Also, I do not want to set the ToolsVersion as everything is working nice and fine in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that this is not the answer for the problem I posted above.  But, this is how I resolved it.

I had gone through forums and documentation and found the basic difference between DEVENV and MSBUILD.  When building with MSBuild assembly resolution happens in a strict manner than in Devenv.

Also, I had gone through the difference between `Assembly.LoadFrom` and `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`.  `Assembly.RefelectionOnlyLoadFrom` considers just the file name and does not check on version, etc.,  This is where MSBuild was loading System.dll from the .Net 4.0 stack where as it has to load System.dll from the silverlight installation path.

With all these in mind, I tried to load the assemblies using `Assembly.LoadFrom` and used `Type.GetType` to resolve the types.  This time, I ran into `StackOverflowException` as the `AssemblyResolve` event was triggered for all the loaded assemblies repeatedly.

This is when I thought of loading the assemblies into a separate appdomain so that I can also unload the loaded assemblies.  I found [this](http://sachabarber.net/?p=560) article very useful and followed a similar pattern to solve the issue.

Though I have the solved issue on hand, I do not want to gain points for this answer. I still feel I have not provided the answer for the issue with MSBuild.

Hope this might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using AppDomainIsolatedTask as base class and try again. This makes handling assemblies a lot easier becasuse the assemblies do not get loaded into the msbuild AppDomain.

This also isolates your event calls to your own AppDomain. So MsBuild also can not disturb you.